# Nested list indexing - Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Cannot seem to get my head around retrieving a  letter 'a' from the list below:

```
new_list = [ 1, 2, ['a, b, c,']]
```

I know i'm supposed to index out 2 by typing:

```
new_list[2]
```

this gives the output:

```
'a, b, c, '
```

Now I'm supposed to type
:
    new_list[2][0]

This should give me the letter `'a'`.
However, the output in Jupyter still gives me:

```
'a, b, c, '
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your list contains only one string, not 3 letters as you thought

Comment: `new_list[2]` shouldn't give `'a, b, c,'`, but `['a, b, c,']`.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

It's perfectly normal, as you can see your list `['a, b, c,']` contains only one element which is `'a, b, c,'`. It's not a list of three elements but a list of only one element. So when you try to access the first element you get the string `'a, b, c,'`.

If you want to do what you are trying to do, you should initialize `new_list` like this:

`new_list = [ 1, 2, ['a', 'b', 'c']]`

Or another way to do it using your initial list would be `new_list[2][0][0]`, and it will get you a single `a`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

`"a,b,c"` appears to be a single string you should `split` this to turn it into an list first, then try to index the elements.

```
new_list = [ 1, 2, ['a, b, c,']]

new_list[2].split(',')[0]  # returns a
```

You can also see the **type** of the elements with

```
type(new_list[2])
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. it does help.

Answer (score 0):

'a, b, c' is a single string in your example. Basically, new_list[2] is a list with a single value in it. if you  want to get 'a' from that just use:

```
new_list[2][0].split(', ')[0]
```

or:

```
new_list[2][0][0]
```

Comment: Thank you.I didn't even consider using the split method